# To be or not to be Catkin?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I really need help sorting a rather large question.

As ROS continues are you going to be sticking with Catkin or moving to something else? And what would that something else be? I happen to like Catkin so I would prefer the former. But someone said to someone at some conference that you will be moving away from Catkin, which is why I can't upgrade all of our packages, in our project, to be Catkin (which is what I was really hoping to do).

Much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209656/to-be-or-not-to-be-catkin?/) by [kleinash](https://answers.ros.org/users/2345/kleinash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2015-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your current packages are using `rosbuild` you should really consider updating to `catkin`.

While the goal is to keep `rosbuild` working there are e.g. issues on Ubuntu 15.04 and newer with the way it works. Changes in upstream code broke it and there will only be a partial workaround to keep it working in most use cases. `rosbuild` is not actively maintained anymore and if for some reason it will break again in the future it might be beyond repair.

Another reason might be that you won't ever be able to `release` your packages when they are based on `rosbuild`.

Now to your main question:
ROS 1 is using `catkin` since Groovy and there is no plan to change that again.

What you might have heard are information about the ROS 2 development. That indeed uses something which is called differently: `ament`. But `ament` is basically an updated version of `catkin` - you could call it `catkin 2`.

A different name was chosen for multiple reasons:

- The so called `devel space` in `catkin` was almost impossible to use when scaling a workspace up to hundreds of packages. Therefore that feature has been removed from `ament`. But the advantage of having a `devel space` (by not copying resources when running your code) has been preserved using a different approach (namely symlinked installs).
- Python packages containing a `setup.py` require to be wrapped in CMake in `catkin`. In `ament` they do not anymore and are being processed with the "native" Python tools directly.
- Some API changed slightly, e.g. some functions in catkin specify implicit target names (which could be considered magic) and `ament` is more clear about that by specifying them explicitly. Some of the `catkin` API was developed with `rosbuild` in mind and some of these design choices should have better been revised.
- The order of some function calls needed to be changed to support currently not possible use cases. One example if the package `catkin_simple` which was an attempt to ease writing CMake code for ROS packages. It was never announce since it had fundamental flaws which couldn't easily be address with the way `catkin` works.

But ultimately `catkin` and `ament` are very similar. `catkin` will be used for ROS 1 and `ament` for ROS 2. There is no plan to "backport" `ament` to ROS 1 and also no plan to support `catkin` for ROS 2.

Therefore I would highly recommend to update your code base from `rosbuild` to `catkin`. A potential step towards ROS 2 in the future will require you to update more of your code. The changes to the CMake files should be very simple at that point.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3